# Апельсины бочками

Tags: python

Бизнесмен Василий после прочтения известной книги решил открыть новый бизнес – отгружать апельсины бочками. Партнерам важно знать сколько именно бочек апельсинов отгружается каждый день.

Мобильный телефон Василия поддерживает только транслит, поэтому он передает сообщения вида "N bochek" . Например, "3 bochki" или "1 bochka" .

Напишите программу, которая выбирает правильное слово (из "bochka" , "bochek" , "bochki" ) в зависимости от N.

Входные данные
Одно число N (0 ≤ N ≤ 1000).

Выходные данные
Фраза на транслите

Пишет, что из 25 тестов, 1 ответ неверный. Что я не учел?

```
N = int(input())

if N <= 10 or N >= 20:
    if (N % 10) == 0 or ((N % 10) >= 5 and (N % 10) <= 9):
        print(str(N) + " bochek")
    elif (N % 10) == 1:
        print(str(N) + " bochka")
    else:
        print(str(N) + " bochki")
else:
    print(str(N) + " bochek")
```

Comment: 111 bochka
112 bochki
113 bochki
114 bochki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забыл учесть числа большие 100. Проблема решается рассмотрением остатка от деления на 100.

```
N = int(input())
M = N % 100

if M <= 10 or M >= 20:
    if (N % 10) == 0 or ((N % 10) >= 5 and (N % 10) <= 9):
        print(str(N) + " bochek")
    elif (N % 10) == 1:
        print(str(N) + " bochka")
    else:
        print(str(N) + " bochki")
else:
    print(str(N) + " bochek")
```

Answer (score 0):

ребят, можно еще проще, просто проверять есть ли в конце 11 или нет.

```
a = int(input())

if (a % 10 > 1) and (a % 10 < 5) and ((a // 10 % 10) != 1):
    print(f'{a} bochki')
elif ((a // 10 % 10) != 1) and (a % 10 == 1):
    print(f'{a} bochka')
else:
    print(f'{a} bochek')
```